# Appending a div so that it appears next to another div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a 'matching' effect using Jquery Drag and Drop.

I have this html -

```
<div class="questionMatch">
    <text class="matchingText clear">Q1</text>
    <div class="dropAcceptor floatRight"></div>
</div>
<div class="questionMatch">
    <text class="matchingText">Q2</text>
    <div class="dropAcceptor"></div>

</div>
<div class="questionMatch">
    <text class="matchingText">Q3</text>
    <div class="dropAcceptor"></div>

</div>
<div class="questionMatch">
    <text class="matchingText clear">Q4</text>
    <div class="dropAcceptor"></div>

</div>
<div class="answerPane">
    <div class="answerMatch floatRight">
        <text class="matchingText">Match1</text>
    </div>
    <div class="answerMatch">
        <text class="matchingText">Match2</text>

    </div>
```

I want it so that when I drag a .answerMatch and drop it onto a .questionMatch, the .answerMatch is appended to the .questionMatch in such a way that it appears next to the text of that .questionMatch.

I've tried this JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".questionMatch").droppable({accept:".answerMatch",
    drop:function(event,ui){
        $(this).find(".dropAcceptor").append($(ui.draggable));
        }
    }

    )
$(".answerMatch").draggable();
```

});

And that appends the element properly, but it appears way above the .questionMatch/not next to it.

What can I do to achieve this effect?

CSS that's being used-

```
.floatLeft{
    float:left;
}
.floatRight{
    float:right;
}
.clear{
    clear:both;
}
```

JSFIDDLE SHOWING PROBLEM-
http://jsfiddle.net/qMxxF/1/

UPDATE-
Inspection in console shows that Jquery drag drop adds positioning in a style attr - I've removed that, and the answerMatch appears below the question now. What is the css to make it appear to the right? When I do a float right, it appears at the right end of the browser.

Comment: can you post some css with it, maybe set up a jsfiddle?

Comment: can I put in Jquery ui in JSfiddle? I don't see an option for that, in any case - added CSS

Comment: yes, you can put jQuery in jsfiddle. Choose it on the left side.

Comment: @praks5432 just add a script tag that links to jQuery UI

Comment: ok, I have deleted my answer. The issue is that draggable does more than just appending the div, it also positions it with left and top values.

Comment: mhmm, I can see that in console, does it make sense to remove that positioning manually using Jquery?

Comment: @praks5432 I have undeleted my answer as it might now address your latest update.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`.after()`](http://api.jquery.com/after/)

```
$(this).after($(ui.draggable));
```

Answer (score 0):

How about replacing your text tags with div tags:

```
<div class="matchingText floatLeft"></div>
```

and:

```
floatLeft {float:left;}
```

or, to be consistent with the answer formaT:

```
<div class="QA">
<div class="questionMatch floatLeft"><text class="matchingText clear">Q1</text></div>
<div class="dropAcceptor floatRight"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: still appears all the way at the top and not next to the element

Comment: thing is - when I do that the questions start appearing on the same line, which shouldn't happen

Comment: Did you try the second part of my answer? It should keep the questions on separate lines.